# How to enable mysqlnd in PHP on a MAMP environment

Tags: php, mysqlnd

Hi I am running a MAMP dev environment and do not have alot of experience re-configuring PHP. However, I see that I need to utilize mysqlnd instead of mysql. How exactly does one do this from terminal in UNIX?

[Link to php install source](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.install.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install the mysqlnd driver with MAMP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637514/how-to-install-the-mysqlnd-driver-with-mamp)