# How to install the mysqlnd driver with MAMP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mamp

Ive done a lot of online research, but I haven't found much on this, which I dont understand. But it seems that the mysql native driver doesn't come with the MAMP stack. For instance the mysqli get_result method doesn't work out of the box. I thought this was an error in my installation but after a clean reinstall the method still doesn't work, so apparently the driver is not install. It seems weird that there is so little material on the topic because a lot of people must be testing local with get_result? 
So it comes down to this: how do i manage to install the mysqlnd driver? :-)

PHP.INI:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;
; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;   extension=modulename.extension
;
; For example, on Windows:
;
;   extension=msql.dll
;
; ... or under UNIX:
;
;   extension=msql.so
;
; Note that it should be the name of the module only; no directory information
; needs to go here.  Specify the location of the extension with the
; extension_dir directive above.


; Extensions

;extension=apcu.so

extension=imap.so
extension=yaz.so
extension=mcrypt.so
extension=gettext.so
extension=pgsql.so
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so

;extension=imagick.so
;extension=tidy.so
;extension=oauth.so
```

Comment: Check you `php.ini` Is the extension enabled?

Comment: hmm Im actually not sure where I would see in the php.ini file if the extension is enabled..

Comment: On your localhost, create a script, and add this line: `<?php php_info();` search for `php.ini`  path. Then open your php.ini, and try to find the `extensions` section. See, is there a `;` char before your `mysqli` extension. If yes, remove it, restart apache.

Comment: i will update my question with the results now.

Comment: in php_info() i have a mysqli section and standard mysqli methods works fine in my scripts.

Comment: [this link](http://verysimple.com/2013/11/05/compile-php-extensions-for-mamp/) has some details on how to compile php with custom extensions

Answer (score 1):

Which PHP version are you using ?

In PHP 5.5 the MySQL original extension was deprecated [1]. MAMP distribution should deleted it from it's base.

Try to use mysqli extension, or you should migrate to pdo_mysql extension.

There it's a converter to change from mysql extension to mysqli one:
https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Converting+to+MySQLi

[1] http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php